# Reading a wedge area of Circular bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, geometry

I am working on a program that takes a Bitmap and converts it into circular form.  The code is as follows:

```
public static Image CropToCircle(Image srcImage, Color backGround)
{
    Image dstImage = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height, srcImage.PixelFormat);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dstImage);
    using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(backGround)) {
        g.FillRectangle(br, 0, 0, dstImage.Width, dstImage.Height);
    }
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddEllipse(0, 0, dstImage.Width, dstImage.Height);
    g.SetClip(path);
    g.DrawImage(srcImage, 0, 0);

    return dstImage;
}
```

It returns the image in circular shape; however I need to read an image wedge in the form of degrees; that is, the circle has 360 degrees and I am trying to write a function that will accept a degree (e.g. 10) and will return the pixels of the image that fall in 10th degree. Such that entire image will be readable in 1 to 360 degrees.

Comment: could you please give me a code start i am more comfortable with customizing the code rather then brain storming with a brand new start. Mathematics is not humble with me :D

Comment: You could use a `GraphicsPath`, and [`GraphicsPath.AddArc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142517(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a path containing the shape of what you want. Then create a `Graphics` on a blank `BitMap`, and call `Graphics.SetClip` with that path.  Then draw your image using that `Graphics` object. Only the pixels that fall within that path will be drawn to the new `BitMap`.

Comment: My hint was misleading and overcomplicated matters. See my answer. Also, someone edited the title; the op was not about a wedge but reading along a radius line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my hint was actually rather misleading, let me make up by giving you a working code:

```
// collect a list of colors from a bitmap with a cetner c and radius r
List<Color> getColorsByAngle(Bitmap bmp, Point c, int r, float angle)
{
    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        int x = (int)(Math.Sin(angle / 180f * Math.PI) * i);
        int y = (int)(Math.Cos(angle / 180f * Math.PI) * i);
        colors.Add(bmp.GetPixel(c.X + x, c.Y + y));
    }
    return colors;
}
```

Here it is at work:

[image]

(The gif is rather quantized for size..)

Note that

- Pixels close to the center will be read multiple time, the center itself even each time
- To collect all outer pixels you need to read as many angles as the circumference of the circle has pixels, ie  2 * PI * radius. So for a circle with a radius of 300 pixels you need to step the angle in 360° / (600 * 3.14) or about 0.2°..
- Also note the the coordinate systems in GDI and in geometry are not the same, neither in the direction of the axes nor the angles. Adapting this is left for you..
- The original version didn't mention a 'wedge area'. To read an area or the whole image simply loop over an angle range in suitable steps!

Comment: Outstanding sir . . this solved my problem you made my day . .